# What is the prob with using Bundle extra to string?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Here is my code.

In the MainActivity.java, I called this method.

```
public void doViewRecord(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityView.class));
}
```

And in the SecondActivity (ActivityView.java).

[This is where I get my error]

```
tv_id = findViewById(R.id.tvId);
    tv_name = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tv_course = findViewById(R.id.tvCourse);

    try{
        extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = extra.getString("id");
        tv_id.setText(id);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        displayError(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The error I get is this.

[image: Error Message]

I already tried the intent then bundle, but still it gives me an error.

Comment: Your intent has no extras. Please show a [mcve] of the code that starts that Activity

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean by no extras?

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras()` returned null, which only happens when you've not put any extras in that Intent

Comment: The second block of code here is unrelated to the error... You should show where you called `startActivity` before the first block

Comment: Where in your code do you *think* you're adding extras?

Comment: See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the string early on the intent

```
public void doViewRecord(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityView.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", "your-id");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```